# Where does Beats send the data?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elastic-cloud, elastic-beats

I have a theoretical question about Beats.

If I understand correctly, Logstach allows to easily parse the received data and ingest it to ElasticSearch. So my question is, does Beats send the retrieved information directly to a Logstach profile or does Beats itself modify the data and ingest it directly into ElasticSearch?

Thanks in advance for your help

**EDIT :**

*Important message*

> To summarize, when I configure Filebeat, I only fill in the
> information from Elastic Cloud as output. That is to say the cloud ID
> and the password of elasticsearch. So I don't fill in any output
> information. My question is, when I use a module (Fortinet for
> example), will Filebeat process the information and send it directly
> to ElasticSearch or will it send it to Logstach by default? I need to
> try to understand as much as possible to write a paper on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can have both the option, you can send the data from beats to directly Elasticsearch or send it to logstash where again in logstash configuration you can mention which Elasticsearch it needs to send the data.

Refer [configure the output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuring-output.html#configuring-output) page for more details and configurations ie Elasticsearch, kafka, redis, console etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So let's say we use Filbeat with any module (Fortinet for example). Does Filebeat parse the information or send it directly to a Logstach profile?

Comment: @SénéchalJulien it should be

Comment: In my case, I use Elastic Cloud. So I just configure my filebeat.yml file using the Elasticsearch cloud ID and password.

Comment: @SénéchalJulien, thats totally fine

Comment: Yes but the question is that I don't define myself if the information goes in logstach or in elasticsearch. Hence my question in fact :/

Comment: @SénéchalJulien didn't get you, can you explain more

Comment: To summarize, when I configure Filebeat, I only fill in the information from Elastic Cloud as output. That is to say the cloud ID and the password of elasticsearch.

So I don't fill in any output information.

My question is, when I use a module (Fortinet for example), will Filebeat process the information and send it directly to ElasticSearch or will it send it to Logstach by default? 

I need to try to understand as much as possible to write a paper on this.